# Finding paths in (DAG) directed acyclic graph given destination

Tags: f#, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say I have this array:

```
let reportStructure = [|(2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 2); (5, 3); (6, 4); (7, 3)|]
```

where the first `int` in a tuple reports to the second `int`.

I can map that really easily with

```
let orgMap = Map.ofArray reporting
```

From there, I could easily get a list of all the ints that report to 2 with

```
orgMap 
|> Map.filter (fun _ key -> key = 2)
```

which returns

```
map [(3, 2); (4, 2)]
```

What I'd really like to see, however, is the entire structure, from 2 all the way down.  For example, I'd like to find a way that could give me the sample output

```
map [(3, 2); (4, 2); (5, 3); (6, 4); (7, 3)]
```

if I'm looking for person 2 or

```
map [(5, 3); (7, 3)]
```

if I'm interested in person 3.

Can I do this?  If so, how?  Is there another structure other than a `map` that would be a better way to make this happen?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When I commented about changing the title I thought you wanted to ask a new question, after thinking about it I see what you meant. I changed the title but since it is your question obviously you should change it to something else if this does not suit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OCaml is close to F# and trying to find Topological sort in F# was not turning up anything useful I looked for OCaml code.

I found [An Introduction to Objective Caml](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/classes/2011/w4115-fall/ocaml.pdf) which had a solution to your problem using Depth First Search and used it as the basis for this answer. Also because you are new to F# you can review the document and see how the code is derived. Oddly I took a look at the remainder of the document after posting this and he has a more advanced version of DFS latter in the document.

Your input is an array `[| |]` but your answer is a list `[]` so I did most of the work as list.

The answers are not in the same order as you had, but they are in the same format.

```
    let reportStructure = [|(2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 2); (5, 3); (6, 4); (7, 3)|]

    //
    //  6 -> 4 -> 2
    //  5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 
    //  7 -> 3

    // val revStructure : tl:('a * 'b) list -> ('b * 'a) list
    let revStructure tl = List.map (fun (a,b) -> (b,a)) tl

    // val mem : item:'a -> list:'a list -> bool when 'a : equality
    let mem item list = List.exists (fun x -> x = item) list 

    // val successors : n:'a -> edges:('a * 'b) list -> 'b list when 'a : equality
    let successors n edges = 
        let matching (s,_) = s = n
        List.map snd (List.filter matching edges)

    // val dist : pred:'a -> succs:'b list -> ('a * 'b) list
    let dist pred succs = List.map (fun y -> (pred,y)) succs

    // val dfsPairs : edges:('a * 'a) list -> start:'a -> ('a * 'a) list when 'a : equality
    let dfsPairs edges start =
        let rec dfsPairsInner edges visited start result = 
            match start with 
            | [] -> List.rev (revStructure result) 
            | n::nodes -> 
                if mem n visited then 
                    dfsPairsInner edges visited nodes result
                else 
                    let predecessors = dist n (successors n edges)
                    let result =
                        match predecessors with
                        | [] -> result
                        | _ -> predecessors @ result
                    dfsPairsInner edges (n::visited) ((successors n edges) @ nodes) result
        dfsPairsInner edges [] [start] []

    let revEdges = revStructure (List.ofArray reportStructure)

    let result = dfsPairs revEdges 2
    // val result : (int * int) list = [(4, 2); (3, 2); (7, 3); (5, 3); (6, 4)]

    let result = dfsPairs revEdges 3
    // val result : (int * int) list = [(7, 3); (5, 3)]
```

Comment: Your earlier comments put me onto writing the DFS algorithms myself in `F#` which, as a relative newcomer, was challenging, but what you provided here--and the link to the original source--is incredibly helpful.  Thanks!

Now that I know what this problem is called, "Topological sorting," I'm wondering if it might be helpful to change the title of the question.  Any idea how that can be done?  Might be helpful for future searches.

Comment: Since your question already has two answers based on DFS (depth first search), I would leave this one alone and start a new question. Even if the question is very similar to this one changing questions after answers are given is frowned upon. Also asking a new question will get you more points. :) Just make the new question different enough that it doesn't get flaged as duplicate.

Comment: Also I did not use Topological sorting for the answer, it uses DFS. I started to use Topological sorting but backed off of that as an answer because it was getting more complicated than DFS an as you are new to F# didn't want to jump into a more complicated answer than was needed.

Comment: To change the title just click on edit (I know it is gray but it is active)

Comment: After thinking about you comment of changing the title you are correct, you should just change the title for this question. I was thinking that you wanted to put the word `ToplogicalSort` in the title but shouldn't have. As a suggestion, make it something that will attract attention and you should get move votes, but not to generic or it will get changed by people like me. e.g. `How to find path(s) in a graph given the destination`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to get a list of pair of ints with "numbers" that directly or indirectly report to some "root". 
Here is an easy but inefficient solution:

```
let reportStructure = [|(2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 2); (5, 3); (6, 4); (7, 3)|]

let reportStructureSet = 
    reportStructure |> Set.ofArray

let reportingDirectlyTo root raportsToSet = 
    raportsToSet 
    |> Set.filter(fun (_, key) -> key = root) 

let addNextGeneration previousIteration raportsToSet = 
    let numbersLowerInHierarchy = previousIteration |> Set.map fst
    raportsToSet |> Set.filter(
        // select only those elements from raportsToSet...
        fun (num, supervisor) -> 
            // ...which either are already in previousIteration 
            (Set.contains (num, supervisor) previousIteration) || 
            // ...or are "below" someone from previousIteration
            (Set.contains supervisor numbersLowerInHierarchy))

let reportingDirectlyOrIndirectlyTo root raportsToSet = 
    // applies addNextGeneration until is "stabilizes" on some value
    let rec fixPointHelper previousIteration = 
        let nextIteration = addNextGeneration previousIteration raportsToSet
        if nextIteration = previousIteration
            then nextIteration
            else fixPointHelper nextIteration

    // set of numbers directly reporting to root
    let reportsDirectly = reportingDirectlyTo root raportsToSet
    // start "iteration" using numbers directly reporting to root
    fixPointHelper reportsDirectly

let reportingDirectlyOrIndirectlyToList root raportsToSet =
    reportingDirectlyOrIndirectlyTo root raportsToSet
    |> Set.toList
```

If you want to implement an efficient solution, you should interpret `reportStructureSet` as a graph in following way:

- `int`s are vertices
- pair of `int`s are directed edges

Then simply check which edges are reachable from "root" using a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Answer (score 0):

I like f# puzzles, so I took a stab at this one. I hope that you enjoy.

```
let orgList = [(2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 2); (5, 3); (6, 4); (7, 3)]

let orgMap =
    orgList
    |> List.fold (fun acc item -> 
        let key = snd item
        match Map.tryFind key acc with 
        | Some(value) -> 
            let map' = Map.remove key acc
            Map.add(key) (item::value) map'
        | None -> 
            Map.add(key) (item::[]) acc
        ) Map.empty<int, (int*int) list> 

let findReports supervisor = 
    let rec findReports' acc collection = 
        match collection with 
        | head::tail -> 
            (findReports' (head::acc) tail) 
            @   match Map.tryFind (fst head) orgMap with
                | Some(value) -> (findReports' [] value)
                | None -> []
        | [] -> acc    
    findReports' [] (Map.find supervisor orgMap)    

findReports 2
|> List.map fst
|> List.distinct
```

returns

```
val it : int list = [3; 4; 5; 7; 6]
```

`findReports 2` returns

```
val it : (int * int) list = [(3, 2); (4, 2); (5, 3); (7, 3); (6, 4)]
```

---

I'll break it down to clarify.

```
let orgList = [ (1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6); (4, 5); (5, 6); (5, 7) ]
```

We take your list of tuples and create a functional map of boss to ((report,boss) list). This might be known as an adjacency list, which is used for traversing graphs.

```
let orgMap =
    orgList
    |> List.fold (fun acc item -> 
        let key = snd item
        match Map.tryFind key acc with
```

If there is a list of reports under a boss, add to that list.

```
        | Some(reports) -> 
            let map' = Map.remove key acc
            Map.add(key) (item::reports) map'
```

Otherwise, add to an empty list and insert into the dictionary.

```
        | None -> 
            Map.add(key) (item::[]) acc
```

Start with an empty map as an accumulator.

```
        ) Map.empty<int, (int*int) list>
```

Recurse through the items to find all reports.

```
let findReports supervisor = 
    let rec findReports' acc collection = 
        match collection with
```

If there is an item, append it to the accumulator. This is BFS. If you switch the expression before and after the concatenate operator (@), it will become DFS.

```
        | head::tail -> 
            (findReports' (head::acc) tail)
```

Concatenate the current list to the recursive list of reports to reports.

```
            @   match Map.tryFind (fst head) orgMap with
                | Some(value) -> (findReports' [] value)
                | None -> []
```

If at the end of the list, return the list.

```
        | [] -> acc
```

Run the recursive function.

```
    findReports' [] (Map.find supervisor orgMap)
```

Run the function.

```
findReports 7
```

Return only the reports

```
|> List.map fst
```

Don't report the report twice.

```
|> List.distinct
```